# Best answer is split across two posts from same missing user

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This question: [Can I declare a different overlay specification in different beamer modes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13087/1402) just became "Popular" but it needs some help to get into canonical SE format.

Here is the history:  I posted the question to StackOverflow way back when. Andrew and I wrestled with a few solutions, and I ended up accepting one of my own solutions.  Six months later a user named "Gurvan" submitted an answer, which I didn't understand and dismissed as inoperable.  Four months after that Gurvan came back and submitted another answer, which was really just a reiteration of the first answer, but with example code that demonstrated he was right.  Shortly after that the question got migrated here.

Now I feel like Gurvan's answer (in its two parts) is probably the best one.  Ideally his two answers should be one post, with the explanation and the sample code together.  But Gurvan is nowhere to be seen.  He has no TeX.SE account, nor as far as I can tell even a StackOverflow one.

Some options to proceed:

1. I edit his first answer, incorporating his second answer, and flag the second answer for deletion.  The edits might end up being substantial, however.
2. Same as option 1 but with Gurvan's first answer marked as community wiki.
3. Continue the search for Gurvan and do nothing until we find him.

Other suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 18):

I would say, merging the answers is the best choice since they belong together. Select the answer with the most votes, so its position in the answer list would not go down, and insert the text from the other answer. The latter can be deleted then.

No need to make community wiki, since there's no intent yet to edit by other fellow users.

No need to wait, it's CC licensed. If Gurvan would like to be here, he would be, I guess. Still, it remains to be his answer.

And by the way the title could be edited to be a proper question, and the question can be changed to a consistent question without "Edit 1:", "Edit 2:", "Edit 3:" - if somebody wants to see the editing history, it's just one click away. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I'll edit the answer (and the question!)